# Using Model Functions in Views in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a project where i have a decent amount of Eloquent Models, 
on most of the pages I need to use multiple models and their functions to build the page correctly.

I am used to this syntax:

```
use App\CustomFolder\CustomModel;
CustomModel::all(); // or whatever function / data I need
```

Though as said I have about 27 Models now and I need multiple ones on every page. So I created a blade layout (master page) where I link all these models, but now it seems these Models can't be called from the view itself.

So how can I either:

- Make these Models globally available (preferred)
- Make it so the models that I call (`use Model;`) in the layout are also available from my view.

Comment: You can use view composers for this purpose : [Sharing Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) or [for specific views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually should get all your resources in the controller methods and not in your views. This goes against the MVC pattern Laravel and Eloquent both use.

In the controllers you can add and use them with the normal syntax:

`use App\CustomFolder\CustomModel;
CustomModel::all(); // or whatever function / data I need`

Learn more about using controllers in Laravel [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers).

EDIT

To not have to always type `Use Path/To/Model` in every controller, you can add the models to `aliases` in `config/app.php`. That way you can add for example `'CustomModel' => App\Path\To\CustomModel` and use it in your controller methods as `\CustomModel`.

Comment: Though the problem would stay the same ..., how do I avoid having to type multiple models and add them to the view (from the controller) every time. How can I create a global list of models needed in every view (when calling the view from my controller) ?

Comment: @RafaelLambelin did this help you?

Comment: It did, the fact that I should use my models in my controller and not in my view, pointed me in the right direction and the alias helped me shorten my code quite a bit ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Although its a bad practice and will void MVC. But you can do like this inside php tags or {{}} braces in blade.
    \App\Models\ModelName::get();

Comment: In your case it would be \App\CustomFolder\CustomModel::all();